# Are there any compatibility issues in using __FILE__ , __LINE__?

Tags: c++, windows, unix

Are these macros only available with GCC?

- `__FILE__`
- `__LINE__`

Are there any limitations in using these while expecting to compile using some other compiler?

Comment: Those macros are defined in the C++ standard. All compilers must have them.

Comment: The macros are defined by both the C++ and C standards (and were widely available in C before the first C standard), which means that they're available in any compiler (preprocessor) you're likely to lay hands on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are standard macros, guaranteed to be available on any C and C++ compiler (C89, §3.8.8 ¶1; C99, §6.10.8 ¶1; C++98, §16.8 ¶1, C++11, *ibidem*, C++14 *ibidem*). Of course the format of `__FILE__` may vary depending on the exact compiler/platform. Still, they can be controlled through the `#line` directive (mandated by the standard as well).